# Runtime error: Failed to create 0x88 image slot (alpha=1 wide=0) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Was going through my app to clean up the UI for Ipad's and receiving a weird issue. When I go to navigate to one of my views, the view automatically closes once opening and I receive the following error:

> Failed to create 0x88 image slot (alpha=1 wide=0) (client=0xxxxxx)
> [0x5 (os/kern) failure]

It started occurring when I incorporated  `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`
on my view to discard splitview from showing up on Ipads. When I remove it works fine, but splitview would then be shown.

```
       NavigationView{
                    //DISPLAY USERS
                    ScrollView{
                        ForEach ((vm.allUsers), id:\.id ) { user in
                                // localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
                            if user.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(userSearch) || user.gender.contains(userSearch) || user.weight.contains(userSearch) || user.height.contains(userSearch) {
                                FollowingListRow(userUID: user.uid ,userName: user.name,userBio: user.userBio ,userProfileImage: user.profilePictureURL, userExercisePreferences: user.exercisePreferences, userSocialLink: user.userSocialLink)
                                 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                
                .padding(.top, 15) // << add separation from list and search bar
                .navigationBarTitle("Search")
               
            //SEARCH
                .searchable(text: $userSearch ,placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "Search by gender, height or weight") // << always display search bar
                .disableAutocorrection(true) // << disable autocorrect
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) // << for ipad styling
        
    }
        
}
```

**View B**

```
 NavigationLink(destination: UserProfileView(userUID: userUID, name: userName, userBio: userBio, userProfilePicture: userProfileImage, journalCount: jm.userJournalCountNonUser, rm: rm, jm: jm, userSocialLink: userSocialLink, exercisePreferences: userExercisePreferences).padding(.top, -65) ){
            VStack{
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                            WebImage(url: URL(string: userProfileImage))
                                .placeholder(Image("profileDefaultPicture"))
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width:60, height: 60)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .padding(.leading, 20)
                                .padding(.trailing, 25)
                        
                         
                        VStack{
                            HStack{
                                Text("TestName)
                                    .font(.title)
                                    
                                Spacer()
                            }
                         }
```

**User Profile (View C)**

```
 var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { Geo in
            VStack{
                WebImage(url: URL(string: userProfilePicture))
                    .placeholder(Image("profileDefaultPicture").resizable())
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width:150, height: 150)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                       
                HStack{
                    Text(name ?? "" ).bold()
                        .font(.title2)
                        .padding(.bottom, 2)
                }
              }
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: got the same error but only on the simulator (iPad 10th gen). I could not reproduce the warning on 2 real iPad (iOS 15 and 16).

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the **.navigationBarTitle("Search")** sometimes when you add a title to the main view (the view that has the **NavigationView**) while you using the **StackNavigationViewStyle** with iPad this error appears. I don't know how to fix this (maybe it is a bug) but as a workaround, you can try to remove **navigationBarTitle** and add the title to the main view like this:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            // this is your navigation bar
            Text("Your Title")
                .padding()
        }
        VStack {
            // all your contents here...
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity) // <- add this
    }
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

So in your case maybe your code will be something like this:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        // this is your navigation bar
        HStack {
            Text("Search")  // <- Your title is here
                .padding()
        }
        
        // put all your view contents here - below
        
        //DISPLAY USERS
        ScrollView {
            ForEach ((vm.allUsers), id:\.id ) { user in
                    // localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
                if user.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(userSearch) || user.gender.contains(userSearch) || user.weight.contains(userSearch) || user.height.contains(userSearch) {
                    FollowingListRow(userUID: user.uid ,userName: user.name,userBio: user.userBio ,userProfileImage: user.profilePictureURL, userExercisePreferences: user.exercisePreferences, userSocialLink: user.userSocialLink)
                     
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 15) // << add separation from list and search bar
        
//        .navigationBarTitle("Search") // <- remove this
        
        //SEARCH
        .searchable(text: $userSearch ,placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "Search by gender, height or weight") // << always display search bar
        .disableAutocorrection(true) // << disable autocorrect
        
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinite, maxHeight: .infinite)   // <- this is important to add at the top container View of your content
        
    }
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) // << for ipad styling
```